Encrypted passwords for YAJSW - Yet Another Java Service Wrapper
Looking at the YAJSW documentation, a suggested mechanism for decrypting passwords involves:
wrapper.config.script.decryptor = scripts/decrypt.gv
wrapper.ntservice.password=${decryptor.invoke('decrypt'\, 'aplasdfjlk')}

This looked good on the surface until I noticed decrypt.gv or a variant of that file has to be included in the application and the password to decrypt the password is available to almost anyone on a Windows machine to see. Has anyone used a much more secure mechanism built into YAJSW or did you have to write your own implementation?
Tips and suggestions welcome though passing in the password via env variables isn't an option in my application due to customer constraints. Thanks!
